# How to Add Visual Web Developer Express to Context Menu for Quick Editing

Tags: windows-7

I am using Windows 7 and Web Developer Express.

I do not like selecting Visual Web Developer all the time to edit an html, xml, etc. file. Instead, What I like to have is a "Edit with WebDev" menu after right clicking on the file desired to edit.

Can someone show me how to do this via Regedit?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use regedit.

Right click over each type of file in turn.

Select "Open With >" and then "Choose Program..."

Look for "Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express" in the list and select that. If it's not there select "Browse..." and find the exe in

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE

It's called `VWDExpress.exe`.

Though if Web Developer Express is installed correctly it should already be on the "Open With" list. You could try repairing the installation.

Comment: Thanks but your answer is not what I want. I want exactly what I mentioned. Thanks by the way.

Comment: @Aaron - fair enough, but this seems simpler than editing the registry ;)

Comment: I've tried your method but after some time for some reason that menu went away and it happened a couple of times. That's why I need something persistent.

Comment: @Aaron - that would imply something else was going on. Windows doesn't normally lose these settings.